# enum name as function

Tags: c++

What happens if we use the enum name as a function in c++? To elaborate, let me put the following code snippet

```
enum check{
    HELLO,
    HI,
    HOWDY,
    SALAM,
    SALOM,
    STOP
};

void main() {
    int p  = check();
    cout<<p;
}
```

I could assume it may be invoking the default constructor in case of a class or structure, but what happens with an enum?

And if it is some sort of a construtor-like method, does it return 0 ? because 'p' was set to 0.

Comment: you might as well write `int p = int();` this is called _value-initialization_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses a *value-initialized* (just like a `class` or a `struct`) `check` to *copy-initialize* the `int`, and it returns `0`.

And to be clear, you're not using it as a function, that's the syntax for value-initialization.

Just like

```
int p = int();
```

isn't using the type `int` as a function.